# Testcafe t.typeText use { paste: true } by default

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

By default [testcafe](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/) will type value simulating user keyboard typing. I speed up the process by using `paste: true` instead:

```
t.typeText('#username', 'mySuperName', { paste: true })
```

But I have to put it each time I use `.typeText`.

## Is there a way to pass that as default property?

Answer (score 4):

At present, there is no way to specify [`{ paste: true }`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/testcontroller/typetext.html#options) as a default option value for the [`typeText`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/testcontroller/typetext.html) action. I've created a suggestion for your use case in the TestCafe repository - https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4067.